# ¿Como configurar Virtual Host en Servidor VPS Ubuntu, Laravel + AngularJS?

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu

Actualmente tengo un proyecto donde separo la parte del backend y frontend, para el backend utilizo laravel y para el front utilizo AngularJS, esto separado en dos carpetas api (laravel) api_front(angularjs), ambas detro de la carpeta **proyecto**.

Cuando ingreso en el navegador: **http://ip_servidor** automaticamente me carga la parte realizada con angularjs

ya que la configuracion en el servidor la tengo de esta forma

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Virtual Host 1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/proyecto/api_front/

        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

El problema que tengo es que en el proyecto de angularJS utilizo WebServices de la parte realizada con laravel.
Ejemplo de webService: `http://ip_servidor/proyecto/api/public/ws/colaboradores`
pero cuando consulto dicho Web Service en el navegador me sale **Not Found
The requested URL /proyecto/api/public was not found on this server**

Entonces tengo creado un segundo Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:88>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/proyecto/api/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride none
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html/proyecto/api/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride none
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
                DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Pero aun sigue sin funcionarme esta nueva ruta.
Por favor pudieran ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Habilitaste el nuevo virtual host? y otra cosa, le estás diciendo que escuche en el puerto 88, te aseguraste que el puerto esté libre? si hiciste todo esto debes conectarte desde ipdelserver:88

Comment: utilice este comando: sudo a2ensite nuevovirtualhost.conf para habilitarlo, y si el puerto 88 esta habilitado, pues asumo que si porque me permite entrar al primer virtual host. o como deberia hacerlo?

Comment: Estás entrando por http://ipdelservidor:88?

Comment: te refieres a: http://ip_servidor:88/proyecto/api, si es no me funciona.

Comment: Intenta que en lugar de apuntar a `/var/www/html/proyecto/api/` apunte a `/var/www/html/proyecto/public/` o el equivalente de tu estructura, pero que apunte a public

Comment: por el momento nada aun.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que se me ocurre, es que utilices la directiva ServerName para diferenciar ambos proyectos. Primero en /etc/hosts añade dos alias para el host local:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost pr1back pr1front
```

Ahora en cada uno de los virtualhosts que tienes en /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ añade la directiva **ServerName**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName pr1front
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/proyecto/api_front/
```

y en el otro:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName pr1back
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/proyecto/api/
```

Ahora desde el navegador podrás acceder a http://pr1front y a http://pr1back de forma independiente y no tendras el problema que tienes actualmente ya que cualquier petición a la raiz de los proyectos se resolverá correctamente.

Comment: Buen dia, muchas gracias por tu tiempo al darme una respuesta, solo me surge la siguiente duda, si pudieras ayudarme por favor: ¿esto es aplicable a un servidor de DigitalOcean?, me refiero a que solo puede acceder mediante la ip. Perdon si estoy mal. Gracias

Comment: Lo que te he dicho en principio es sólo para trabajar de forma local en una única máquina. Ahora bien, supongo, que si tienes acceso a la configuración de apache en el servidor que dices, no debería haber problema (y en el local añadirias los alias al /etc/hosts apuntando a la ip del servidor).

Comment: todo esto lo estoy trabajando desde el servidor, exacto si tengo acceso a la configuración de apache para este caso como se haría? -